# FSharp Parameterless Function Caching, does it always cache?

Tags: caching, f#

According to  [http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Caching](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Caching)

> F# automatically caches the value of any function which takes no
>   parameters

So why does this work?

```
let random() = System.Random().Next()
```

random is unit -> int
I would expect the output values to be cached and return the same int every time you call random().

Comment: `random()` takes parameter `()` which is `unit`. you are confusing a function and a variable. `let random = System.Random().Next()` initializes a variable `random` that will return the same value on multiple calls.

Comment: `FSharp is supposed to automatically cache the value of any function which takes no parameters.` [citation needed] (and no, https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Caching is not an authoritative source on F#)

Comment: why do you think that F# should automatically *cache* functions results? (I don't want to mock you - I honestly want to know where you got this from in order to try and get rid of this missinformation there)

Comment: @Luaan I have added a citation, so you can see where I became confused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The F# 3.0 specification says no such thing.

A purely functional language would be allowed to do this "substitution" (commonly called "referential transparency"), because in a purely functional language, the function is nothing but its single argument and its single return value. Needless to say, F# is *not* a purely functional language.

*However*, that is not the issue here anyway. `random` is *not* a function without arguments. It takes a single argument (of type `unit`), and returns an integer. As you noted, random's signature is `unit -> int` - that's something completely different from a function that has no argument, which would have a signature of `int`; in other words, a local.

When a function either takes or returns `unit` (or `void`), it shouldn't ever be memoized - it's an obvious sign that the method has side-effects. It's not a fixed rule, but...

Comment: I admit as V.B. and you have noted this is a function that takes unit so it is not parameter-less, But I am now confused, does F# cache parameterless functions at all?

Comment: if with *parameterless functions* you mean values then yeah... if you mean functions from `()` to something than no

Comment: @Luaan ... I don't think we should call that *memoization* - I think you are talking about [*referential transparency*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_(computer_science)) here

Comment: @Carsten Well, that's slightly stricter, but I guess it fits better.

Comment: @HedgeHogFace You're still in the same confusion you had when starting - a parameterless function *is a value*. Every time you do `let i = 3`, you're creating a new paremeter-less function that returns `3`. I can see how this can be confusing if you didn't study the algebra behind this - equating parameter-less functions to simple values is a reasonable simplification you can adopt if you don't want to dig into the math.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the correct way to code my one liner in the question is

```
let good = 
    let r = System.Random()
    fun () -> r.Next()
```

This has the signature **(unit -> int)**. The line *let r = System.Random()* will only be executed once, even though *good()* may be called many times.

This following is not good.

```
let bad() =       
    let r = System.Random()   
    r.Next()
```

This has the signature **unit -> int**. Similar to the one liner in the question. Here the line *let r = System.Random()* will be executed every time *bad()* is called.